# How properly get JSON from remote server using native JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, api, url

I'm getting JSON from remote server (openweathermap.org). What's wrong with my code? Here example of server's response [enter link description here](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=New%20York)

```
var getWeatherJSON = function (city) {
    var httpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    var jsonText;
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        //====jsonText after getting respons equals null====
        jsonText = httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200 ? httpRequest.responseText : null;
    }
    httpRequest.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city, true);
    httpRequest.send();
    return jsonText;
}
```

Comment: you need to do your stuff inside the onreadystatechange(), you can't return the data at the remote url using async. you can also set the third arg of open() to false, but that's lame and then you need to return _httpRequest.responseText_ instead of your var. btw, there is no reason to use ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") for something needing cors; it adds no device support to fork like that.

Comment: Please read the solution posted by me below. In case you are unable to understand, do ask for a clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return the jsonText from either the getWeatherJSON function or the onreadystatechange function. You can only use this data and call a function which can use this data.
Like:

```js
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
  //====jsonText after getting respons equals null====
  jsonText = httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200 ? httpRequest.responseText : null;
  callbackFunction(jsonText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change "true" to "false".It's work.

> httpRequest.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city, false);

if you use "true" ,it's Asynchronous request,you should use "callback function".